# React setState on another element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and to get to grips with it, I'm converting existing project from jQuery to React.

I have six select boxes that update sequentially depending on the selection of the previous select box e.g. select option `FOO` from `select box A` and `select box B` must update with items corresponding to `FOO`.

I'll list some of references at the bottom

**What I have so far:**
I've got `onchange` events using `fetch` to call my api and get the data I want to use to populate the next select box and this is where I'm hitting a wall.

I've written two components `MapControls` and `SelectBox`. `MapControls` has an array of objects in its state that are used to generate a collection of `SelectBox` instances

Here's the `MapControls` component:

```
class MapControls extends React.Component {

state = {
    selectBoxes: [
        {
            id: 'WorkSource',
            name: 'WorkSource',
            title:'Work Source',
            containerId: 'WorkSourceContainer',
            className: 'WorkSource',
            childControllerMethod: 'GetBusinessTypeDropdown',
            items: [{value:0, text:'Select'}, { value: '1', text: 'Routed' }],
            child: 'BusinessType'
        },
        {
            id: 'BusinessType',
            name: 'BusinessType',
            title: 'Business Type',
            containerId: 'BusinessTypeContainer',
            className: 'BusinessType',
            childControllerMethod: 'GetWorkTypeDropdown',
            items: [{ value: 0, text: 'Select' }],
            child: 'WorkType'
        },
        //... more items ...
    ]
}

render() {
    return this.state.selectBoxes.map(selectBox => 
        <div key={selectBox.id} className='col-xs-2'>
            <div id={selectBox.containerId}>
                <SelectBox id={selectBox.id} name={selectBox.name} selectBox={selectBox} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}
};
```

and here's the `SelectBox` component. It's in the `handleChange` event where I want to be able to update the items in another `SelectBox` instance based on the `ref`. See the inline comments that describe my stumbling blocks

```
class SelectBox extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: this.props.selectBox.items };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
    const selectedValue = event.target.value;
    const url = "/Home/" + event.target.dataset.childControllerMethod;
    const data = JSON.stringify({ selectedValue: selectedValue });

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: data
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            console.log("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
    }).then(data => {


        // This updates the selectbox that was changed, which is not what I want
        // this.setState({ items: data})  

        // This is what I was hoping would work, but I've discovered that BusinessType is a DOM element here, so setState is not valid
        // this.refs.BusinessType.setState({ items: data });

        // I hardcorded the 'BusinessType' as a ref just for testing because I know it's valid, but I want this to be dynamic
        // findDOMNode seems to be somewhat of an anti-pattern, so I'd rather not do this. Not that the below code works because sibling is not a React object
        // let sibling = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.BusinessType);
        // sibling.setState({ items: data });   
    });
}


render() 
{

    const optionItems = this.state.items.map((item, index) =>
        <option key={index} value={item.value} >{item.text}</option>
    );



    return <div>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.selectBox.id} >{this.props.selectBox.title}</label>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange} id={this.props.selectBox.id} ref={this.props.selectBox.child} /*data-child={this.props.selectBox.child}*/ data-child-controller-method={this.props.selectBox.childControllerMethod}>
                {optionItems}
            </select>

        </div>
}
};

ReactDOM.render(<MapControls />,
document.getElementById('mapControls')
);
```

Places I've looked:

- http://jamesknelson.com/react-js-by-example-interacting-with-the-dom/
- https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode
- https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
- http://www.mattmorgante.com/technology/dropdown-with-react
- https://davidwalsh.name/get-react-component-element
- https://www.carlrippon.com/react-drop-down-data-binding/

Comment: React built in state management is great when using it for single isolated components, were things get messy is when you want more controlled state.  This is were the concept "Single source of truth" comes in,.  Redux is an example state management system that can be used in React, it's not the only one, in fact I ended up rolling my own using object proxy's, as I found Redux to be too verbose for something that should be really simple.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into Redux, but at this stage, I'd really rather not add an additional layer of complexity - maybe when I'm more familiar with React. It does seem strange to me that the onChange of one node cannot simply update the state of another - that seems like a fundametal omission. I guess I must be missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be wanting is similar to Angular's two way binding using @input @output.

What you can do is the following:

```
class MapControls extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props); // needed
        this.state = {...} // Your declared state above
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }      

    handleChange(data){
       // Here you should receive data change emitted from child components

    }

    render(){
        ...
        <SelectBox id={selectBox.id} name={selectBox.name} selectBox={selectBox} onChange={this.handleChange}

    }
}
```

Handle change listener should happen on the parent component, consider moving the fetch command to the parent instead. **What you need to emit to parent is the event.target of the child**

```
class SelectBox extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: this.props.selectBox.items };
    this.emitChange = this.emitChange.bind(this);
    // Changed funciton's name to emitChange to avoid confusion
}

emitChange(event) {
    const selectedValue = event.target.value;
    const url = "/Home/" + event.target.dataset.childControllerMethod;
    const data = JSON.stringify({ selectedValue: selectedValue });

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: data
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            console.log("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
        // While you could keep this here, it can be sent to parent, it's your decision
        if(!!this.props.onChange){
            // Here you'll emit data to parent via a props function
            this.props.onChange(data);
        }
    });
}


render() {

    const optionItems = this.state.items.map((item, index) =>
        <option key={index} value={item.value} >{item.text}</option>
    );



    return <div>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.selectBox.id} >{this.props.selectBox.title}</label>
        <select onChange={this.emitChange} id={this.props.selectBox.id} ref={this.props.selectBox.child} /*data-child={this.props.selectBox.child}*/ data-child-controller-method={this.props.selectBox.childControllerMethod}>
                {optionItems}
            </select>

        </div>
}
};

ReactDOM.render(<MapControls />,
document.getElementById('mapControls')
);
```

So, this is the general idea, you pass from parent a prop that's a function binded to it (parent), child will have a method that will execute the prop (if exists).

**What I left out of this example:**

You need to consider where to handle the fetch command accordingly (parent or child), remember that state defined in constructors is not updated if props change.

IF you want state to update on component's prop changes you'll have to use event cycles like "componentWillReceiveProps" (deprecated in recent version) or similar.

My general recommendation is **child components should dwell on props**, whereas **parent component should handle state to be passed to child as props**.

Passing function handles as props is a good way to intercommunicate your components, you could also use RXJS and pass **Subscription** types as props.

Comment: Thanks for your details answer @Gabriel Balsa Cantú . It pointed me in the right direction however, I had to make several modifications for it to work. I find it bizarre that React makes it such a mission for one onchage event to trigger that of a sibling

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I found is as follows. Thank you to Gabriel for pointing me in the right direction. The final solution could be used for any filter component that needs to react to users' selections

I followed Gabriel's recommendation to call the parent's onChange event and handle the setting of the state in there.

I created the `triggerSibling` method so that I could hook into the `componentDidUpdate()` event and cascade the changes down the hierarchy of select boxes. So the `onChange` and `componentDidMount` events trigger the same logic.

Then in the MapControls `onChange`, I followed Gabriel's suggestion to handle the data there.

In the call to the parent's onChange event, I pass the data from the api call, along with the name of the child to target

The children of the parent component are accessible through `this.refs` and I discovered that I can access the specific child by using its name as a key in the array of children, as follows
`this.refs[data.child].setState({ items: data.items })`

I used the `componentDidMount()` event to set the initial value of the first selectBox and trigger the cascade of updates on the initial load

MapControls component:

```
class MapControls extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props); // needed
    this.state = {
        selectBoxes: [
            {
                id: 'WorkSource',
                name: 'WorkSource',
                title: 'Work Source',
                containerId: 'WorkSourceContainer',
                className: 'WorkSource',
                childControllerMethod: 'GetBusinessTypeDropdown',
                items: [{ value: 0, text: 'Select' }, { value: 'ROUTED', text: 'Routed' }],
                child: 'BusinessType'
            },
            {
                id: 'BusinessType',
                name: 'BusinessType',
                title: 'Business Type',
                containerId: 'BusinessTypeContainer',
                className: 'BusinessType',
                childControllerMethod: 'GetWorkTypeDropdown',
                items: [{ value: 0, text: 'Select' }],
                child: 'WorkType'
            },
            ... more ...
        ]
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}      


handleChange(data) {
    this.refs[data.child].setState({ items: data.items });

}


render() {
    return this.state.selectBoxes.map(selectBox => 
        <div key={selectBox.id} className='col-xs-2'>
            <div id={selectBox.containerId}>
                <SelectBox id={selectBox.id} name={selectBox.name} ref={selectBox.name} selectBox={selectBox} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}
};
```

SelectBox component:

```
class SelectBox extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: this.props.selectBox.items };
    this.emitChange = this.emitChange.bind(this);
}


triggerSibling (idOfDropdownToUpdate, selectedValue, url) {

    const data = JSON.stringify({ selectedValue: selectedValue });

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: data,
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            console.log("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
    }).then(data => {

        if (!!this.props.onChange) {
            // add the target to be updated as `child` property in the data passed to the parent
            this.props.onChange({ child: this.props.selectBox.child, items: data });
        }
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    // Set the value of the first selectBox AFTER it has mounted, so that its `onChange` event is triggered and the `onChange` events cascade through the rest of the selectBoxes
    if (this.props.name == "WorkSource") {
        this.setState({ items: [{ value: 'ROUTED', text: 'Routed' }] });
    }
}

// triggered when the component has finished rendering
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const url = "/Home/" + this.props.selectBox.childControllerMethod;
    if (this.props.selectBox.child != "")
        this.triggerSibling(this.props.selectBox.child, this.state.items[0].value, url)
}

emitChange(event) {
    const idOfDropdownToUpdate = event.target.dataset.child;
    const selectedValue = event.target.value;
    const url = "/Home/" + event.target.dataset.childControllerMethod;
    this.triggerSibling(idOfDropdownToUpdate, selectedValue, url)
}


render() 
{

    const optionItems = this.state.items.map((item, index) =>
        <option key={index} value={item.value} >{item.text}</option>
    );



    return <div>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.selectBox.id} >{this.props.selectBox.title}</label>
        <select onChange={this.emitChange} id={this.props.selectBox.id} data-child={this.props.selectBox.child} data-child-controller-method={this.props.selectBox.childControllerMethod}>
                {optionItems}
            </select>

        </div>
}
};
```